# AutoLayout in iOS using storyboard only

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard, ios-autolayout

I have a ImageView whose top constraint is 80 and center. I have  two textView with margin of 100 from top consecutive object and 100 margin from both left and right.

When I am trying to implement `auto-layout` i am not able to do so because of many warning as shown in the figure :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it  is better to post size inspector screenshot.

Comment: What are the constraints for textview2? By any chance did you set Height and width constraints too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Every time when you give constraint do following things :-**

1. Fix the width and height of the element.
2. Give one vertical constraint and one horizontal constraint.
3. Don't do over-constraint.
4. Update it where it is showing warning.

Answer (score 2):

your imageview and textviews are not comfortable with your current constraints .if you add top and centre constraints for uiimageview you must add the height and width constraints for accessing the x value.

and also you just add height constraints for both of your textviews and try again. thankyou

Answer (score 1):

If you set Left/Right margin and CenterX, your system is over-constraint.

You should set : Left + Center or Right+Center or Left+Right.

Next you should change the content Hugging and Compression priority.